# What is directory under selected numbers in redmi call recording settings?

Tags: android-10, redmi

What is directory button under selected numbers in redmi call recording settings?
Does it mean contacts?

Device : redmi note 7 pro
[image]

Comment: @Robert could you suggest some title? In github, the body is not necessary. Here it's hard to do that. If we give the title as body, it won't be posted.

Comment: Does it show additional options when you enable Directory?

Comment: @Firelord nope.